# Changing a few lines gives different results even though it shouldn't

Tags: html, css

**Problem has been resolved, thank you to everyone who has helped me with this. The problem was that I was using <.style> tags in the css file which is a HTML tag, which is not read properly in the css making varying things happen.**

I working on an assignment for my HTML class and were getting into .css for external setup.

What I've been noticing is when I move one block of code into anothers spot, the entirety of my webpage changes, but what I moved seems to "no longer exist".

### My css code is

```
    <style>

    body { background-color: #6699ff;
            color: #d5e3ff;
            font-family: verdana; }

    header { background-color: #6699ff;
            color: #003366;
            font-family: serif; }

    h1 { line-height: 200%; }

    nav { font-weight: bold; }

    #category { font-style: bold;
            background-color: #6699ff;
            color: #003366;
            font-size: 1.1em; }

    footer { font-size: 0.60em;
            font-style: italic; }

    </style>
```

---

And the page looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhG5F.jpg

### But when I move the the body to where the header is

```
    <style>


    header { background-color: #6699ff;
            color: #003366;
            font-family: serif; }

    body { background-color: #6699ff;
            color: #d5e3ff;
            font-family: verdana; }

    h1 { line-height: 200%; }

    nav { font-weight: bold; }

    #category { font-style: bold;
            background-color: #6699ff;
            color: #003366;
            font-size: 1.1em; }

    footer { font-size: 0.60em;
            font-style: italic; }

    </style>
```

---

The page ends up looking like this... https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y4De.jpg

I'm really confused as to why it only uses the second "block" to actually get what the page should look like.

I can edit in my index page if you need to see that as well, but I'm pretty sure it's just an issue with how I'm coding the css file.

Here's the Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<link rel= "stylesheet" href="fishcreek.css">

    <header>
        <title> Fish Creek Animal Hospital </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <h1> Fish Creek Animal Hospital </h1>
    </header>

        <nav>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
            <a href="services.html">Services</a> &nbsp;
            <a href="askvet.html">Ask the Vet</a> &nbsp;
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </nav>

    <body>
    <dl>

        <dt><strong>Full Service Facility</strong></dt>
            <dd>Veterinarians and staff are on duty 24 hours a day, 7 days a week.</dd>
        <dt><strong>Years of Experience</strong><dt>
            <dd>Fish Creek Veterinarians have provided quality, dependable care for your <br>
            beloved animals since 1984.</dd>
        <dt><strong>Open door Policy</strong></dt>
            <dd>Our Professionals welcome owners to stay with their pets during any medical <br>
            procedure.</dd>
        <dl>
            1-800-555-5555 <br> 1242 Grassy Lane <br> Fish Creek, WI 55534
        </dl>

    </dl>
    </body>

    <footer>
    <small><i>Copyright &copy 2014 Fish Creek Animal Hospital <br>
    <a href="mailto:Johnathon@Olivas.com">Johnathon@Olivas.com</a></i>       </small>
    </footer>
</html>
```

If anyone knows whats wrong with mine, or why it seems to be doing that, I'd love to know! Thanks in advance -John

As a temporary fix to the problem, I was able to add a small single line of code as the "fodder" to being skipped and the header now works the way it's supposed to, and the rest is all according to plan!

```
THEFIX! {background-color: #6699ff;}
```

That's all I had to do and it works... kinda, I just hope that I can figure out how to get rid of "thefix" so it works without it.

Thanks for the help everyone, sorry that it wasn't worded very well and probably didn't make much sense, but yea... temporary workarounds ftw

Comment: nothing wrong with your css file, I think you must put your html code here.
i want to look at your header tag. cause i don't know header is a class or a tag in your html code. 
if it's a class then .header not header{} in your css

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please provide a full code snippet (edit post and Ctrl-M in question textarea)

Comment: Both of you, the code has been added, should be fully visible now :) Also, I'm aware that some of the <strong> <i> things are redundant, but I'll be getting to those after I get the whole page to work properly lol

Comment: OS/Browser? For me both variants looks equal to http://i.imgur.com/GxTfpTs.jpg

Comment: Windows 8.1 Chrome | Also all the text is supposed to be a dark blue, which the first picture has, but second doesn't. This whole thing is very confusing to me lol

Comment: Ok, I've understand, wait for a minute.

Comment: Okay, it seems that I may have found a work around so that I can still use the header, and not have to put it into h1 like I did on my last assignment... check the bottom of the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **shouldn't** use `<style>` and `</style>` in your css files — it's a html tags, not css syntax.

What's going on in your case:

You are trying to apply css rules to `<style> body` selector or `<style> header` selector depending on the order. There is no such elems in your html, so it in fact doesn't applies your first rule.

Comment: I don't think I have any script tags in the .css unless I'm blind and completley oblivious lol

Comment: Ohhh I think I get what you said, by script you meant Style, which is probably a "type" of script right? if thats the case, this makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I try something like this, and change the order css code for header and body the result is same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

/*
body { background-color: #6699ff;
        color: white;
        font-family: verdana; }

header { background-color: #6699ff;
        color: red;
        font-family: serif; }
*/
header { background-color: #6699ff;
        color: red;
        font-family: serif; }
body { background-color: #6699ff;
        color: white;
        font-family: verdana; }


</style>
</head>
<body>

<article>
  <header>
    <h1>Most important heading here</h1>
    <h3>Less important heading here</h3>
    <p>Some additional information here.</p>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor set amet....</p>
</article>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See, that's the thing, when I do your suggestion, it's as if the header style doesn't even exist (shown in picture 2 - the H1 is now using the Verdana font where its supposed to be using the serif font (which doesn't look any different then times new roman?) )

Comment: do have try the code I give ? what I mean is the result is running well. try change the order and teh result is same, running well.

Comment: Actually, yea yours does do somethign different, but I need the style to be called from a css file, which I think is where the problem is at.

Comment: I try it on firefox and chrome, it's running well too.
I try your code on firefox and chrome and it's running well too.
:D

Comment: try to make your style look different, like color text white and red. so you will notice it any different or not if you change the order your css script.
good luck, if you call your css file, often cache is become an important variable.

Comment: I think the easiest way to see if my header tag is even working is by changing the font family into Chiller as it gives a unique look to text. (adding pictures hold on) Normal where it seems header is non existant. http://i.imgur.com/dN99gDQ.jpg     Then, this is when I change the body to use font family chiller: http://i.imgur.com/ebZuHps.jpg As I'm sure you can see the H1 is now using the chiller font, where it should be serif.

Comment: some font family may be not running on another server.